# How to disable previous date and get time stamp along with the date using html input type 'date' in angular7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using html input type ='date'. I need to disable back date entries and need to get time stamp along with the date using angular 7

**code**

```
                <textbox
                        [bindProperty]="(observables.viewModel$ | async)?.earlierStartTime"
                        [type]="'date'"                    
                        [min]="2020-04-13"
                        [selectOnFocus]="true">
                </textbox>
```

Comment: which library use textbox element?

Comment: which libraray uses textbox please share code on stackbliz